# Generic function to compute a hash (digest::Digest trait) and get back a String

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around this problem. I am trying to write a generic function which can take any `digest::Digest` and spits out a string form of the computed digest  ("hex string").

Here is [the non-generic version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a51b70deb2e87450f2908273491ab06e) as minimal example:

```
#![forbid(unsafe_code)]
#![forbid(warnings)]
extern crate sha2; // 0.9.1

use sha2::{Sha256, Digest}; // 0.9.1

fn main() {
    let hash = Sha256::new().chain("String data").finalize();
    let s = format!("{:x}", hash);
    println!("Result: {}", s);
}
```

... and here is my attempt [at a generic version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e1a68450c2053ffa2ecaeee3a9e0ab7):

```
#![forbid(unsafe_code)]
#![forbid(warnings)]
extern crate sha2; // 0.9.1
extern crate digest; // 0.9.0

use digest::Digest;
use sha2::Sha256;

fn compute_hash<D: Digest>(input_data: &str) -> String {
    let mut hasher = D::new();
    hasher.update(input_data.as_bytes());
    let digest = hasher.finalize();
    format!("{:x}", digest)
}

fn main() {
    let s = compute_hash::<Sha256>("String data");
    println!("Result: {}", s);
}
```

... which gives the following error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: cannot add `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize` to `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:21
   |
13 |     format!("{:x}", digest)
   |                     ^^^^^^ no implementation for `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize + <D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::LowerHex` for `digest::generic_array::GenericArray<u8, <D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize>`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::LowerHex::fmt`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
9  | fn compute_hash<D: Digest>(input_data: &str) -> String where <D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize: std::ops::Add {
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground`.
```

Now suppose I understand the error correctly, the implementation of `std::fmt::LowerHex` used by `format!()` *appears* to require `std::ops::Add` for the `OutputSize` of the `GenericArray<u8, N>` (i.e. the `N`) which is returned by `.finalize()`. However, the non-generic example suggests that there is such an implementation for `ArrayLength<u8>`.

So, given I cannot implement the `std::ops::Add` trait for an external type, how can I satisfy the compiler in this case?

Or maybe to rephrase my question, although I - being new with Rust - am not a 100% sure it is what I want: how do I tell the compiler to treat `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize` the same as `ArrayLength<u8>`?

**NB:** I am relatively new with Rust, so please keep that in mind and kindly refer to the *exact* piece of documentation applicable to my case, rather than "the documentation" in general. I have scoured the documentation for `digest`, for various of the implementers of `digest::Digest`, for this error and for (what I thought were) similar issues and the traits topics in the Rust Book (2018 edition) for nearly three hours before I asked. Thanks.

---

In the second example I am using `use digest::Digest;`. That's because in the future other hash algorithms are supposed to follow and it seemed to make more sense to use `digest::Digest` directly instead of the re-exported `Digest` from one of the implementers. If there is a reason against that, feel free to remark on it.

Comment: May be worth noting that the `digest` crate uses `generic_array` to work around the lack of language support for [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2000). It seems likely that a future version of the language could allow `digest` to support this usage in a more direct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust requires that you specify all the functionality you use in generics. The note:

```
   |                     ^^^^^^ no implementation for `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize + <D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize`
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize`
```

is trying to say that we are using `Add` on the type `D::OutputSize` but not requiring it as a constraint, which we can do like so:

```
fn compute_hash<D: Digest>(input_data: &str) -> String
    where D::OutputSize: std::ops::Add
```

If you make this change, you'll come to the next error:

```
   |                     ^^^^^^ the trait `digest::generic_array::ArrayLength<u8>` is not implemented for `<<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize as std::ops::Add>::Output`
```

so there is another requirement, but we can add that too:

```
fn compute_hash<D: Digest>(input_data: &str) -> String
    where D::OutputSize: std::ops::Add,
          <D::OutputSize as std::ops::Add>::Output: digest::generic_array::ArrayLength<u8>
```

This will compile.

But let's dive into the reasons why these constraints are necessary. [`finalize`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.Digest.html#tymethod.finalize) returns `Output<D>` and we know that it is the type [`GenericArray<u8, <D as Digest>::OutputSize>`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/type.Output.html). Evidently `format!("{:x}", ...)` requires the trait `LowerHex` so we can see when this type satisfies this trait. [See](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.4/generic_array/struct.GenericArray.html#impl-LowerHex):

```
impl<T: ArrayLength<u8>> LowerHex for GenericArray<u8, T>
where
    T: Add<T>,
    <T as Add<T>>::Output: ArrayLength<u8>,
```

That looks familiar. So the return type of `finalize` is satisfies `LowerHex` if these constraints are true.

But we can get at the same thing more directly. We want to be able to format using `LowerHex` and [we can say that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8330bb21dc9334fc7ae8a658de46265e):

```
fn compute_hash<D: Digest>(input_data: &str) -> String
    where digest::Output<D>: core::fmt::LowerHex
```

Since this can directly express what we use in the generic function, this seems preferable.

Comment: Thanks so much. Especially the path to your solution is what's interesting to me as a student of Rust.

Answer (score 3):

> So, given I cannot implement the std::ops::Add trait for an external type, how can I satisfy the compiler in this case?

You don't need to *implement* it, you need to require that it *is* implemented.

> how do I tell the compiler to treat `<D as sha2::Digest>::OutputSize` the same as `ArrayLength<u8>`?

This is the right idea, but since `ArrayLength` is a trait, not a type, you want "is constrained to implement", not "the same as".

This will compile:

```rust
#![feature(associated_type_bounds)]

...

fn compute_hash<D>(input_data: &str) -> String
where
    D: Digest,
    D::OutputSize: ArrayLength<u8> + std::ops::Add<Output: ArrayLength<u8>>,
{
```

The catch is that it uses the unstable feature `associated_type_bounds` — that's the part where an associated type, `D::OutputSize`, appears on the left side of a trait bound, `SomeType: SomeTrait`.

To stick to stable Rust, we can introduce some ugly type parameters to avoid associated type bounds by making them *equality* instead:

```rust
fn compute_hash<D, L1, L2>(input_data: &str) -> String
where
    D: Digest<OutputSize = L1>,
    L1: ArrayLength<u8> + std::ops::Add<Output = L2>,
    L2: ArrayLength<u8>,
{
    ...
}

fn main() {
    let s = compute_hash::<Sha256, _, _>("String data");
    println!("Result: {}", s);
}
```

But this requires writing `, _, _>` at every call site.

There may be a better way to do this — I'm fairly new to Rust and not experienced with the ins and outs of the sort of type-level programming `ArrayLength` is doing, in Rust.