# Returning a hash as String rust

Tags: hash, rust, cryptography

I want to print the output from a hashing function to stdout. I use the groestl hash function but i suppose it works the same as sha or others. Doing it like this prints the hash as it should:

```
fn create_hash<D: Digest>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> GenericArray<u8, D::OutputSize> {
  hasher.update(msg);
  hasher.finalize()
}

fn main() {
  let hasher = Groestl256::default();
  let res = create_hash("asdfasdf", hasher);
  println!("{:x}", res);
}
```

Outputs: db102d374ae45b130ae49e91dcc7b648b86ba1a0415a32dcce7806d46f316460

Now i want to do a match to make the other algorithms(Groestl512,...) also usable.

```
    let dig = match algorithm {
        HashTypes::groestl224 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl224::default())
        }
        HashTypes::groestl256 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl256::default())
        }
        HashTypes::groestl384 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl384::default())
        }
        HashTypes::groestl512 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl512::default())
        }
    };
    let res = HashGroestl::create_hash("asdfasdf", Groestl256::default());
    
    println!("Result: {:x}", res);
```

This results in the match arms having incompatible types due to different sizes of the returning array. I tried to bypass this by returning a String instead of the GenericArray.

When i want to return a String from `create_hash` with `format!("{:x}", hasher.finalize())` results in following error:

```
cannot add `<D as groestl::Digest>::OutputSize` to `<D as groestl::Digest>::OutputSize`
the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `<D as groestl::Digest>::OutputSize`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::LowerHex` for `aes::cipher::generic_array::GenericArray<u8, <D as groestl::Digest>::OutputSize>`
required by `std::fmt::LowerHex::fmt`
```

I also tried around with converting the array to a Vec or with .as_slice().

So how can i either return a String like above or make the match arms compatible?

EDIT: Okay, just found the solution in [Generic function to compute a hash (digest::Digest trait) and get back a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326373/generic-function-to-compute-a-hash-digestdigest-trait-and-get-back-a-string) to return as a string.
But the other part with making the match arms compatible still interests me, so if someone has an answer for that, you're welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When i want to return a `String` from create_hash with `format!("{:x}", hasher.finalize())` results in [...] error

The problem is that `create_hash` is generic over `D`, which is only required to implement `Digest`. While concrete implementation of `Digest` you are supplying it also satisfy the `LowerHex` trait needed for `format!("{:x}")` to accept them, the signature of `create_hash` doesn't reflect that.

To fix it, you should use an additional constraint on digest's output, like this:

```
fn create_hash<D>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> String
where
    D: Digest,
    digest::Output<D>: std::fmt::LowerHex,
{
    hasher.update(msg);
    format!("{:x}", hasher.finalize())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4eb74a86306317d1258d4da7a6da2da0)

To make the different match arms compatible, you must introduce indirection and therefore allocation. The above example already does it with `String`, so you could have your match arms include `format!("{:x}", create_hash(...))` and they'd be compatible automatically. But if you don't like that, you can also make `create_hash` return `Vec<u8>` instead:

```
fn create_hash<D: Digest>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> Vec<u8> {
    hasher.update(msg);
    hasher.finalize().as_slice().to_vec()
}
```

That will make the match arms compatible, but `{:x}` will no longer work. You can also make `create_hash()` return a boxed object that implements `LowerHex`:

```
fn create_hash<D>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> Box<dyn LowerHex>
where
    D: Digest,
    digest::Output<D>: LowerHex,
{
    hasher.update(msg);
    Box::new(hasher.finalize())
}
```

The match arms then work out:

```
fn main() {
    let res = if true {
        create_hash("asdfasdf", Sha256::default())
    } else {
        create_hash("asdfasdf", Sha512::default())
    };
    println!("{:x}", res.as_ref());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9e67041cbf65104a67879928bbec4fb)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have different output types in each variant you matching:

```rust
let dig = match algorithm {
        HashTypes::groestl224 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl224::default()) // type #1
        }
        HashTypes::groestl256 => {
            create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl256::default()) // type #2
        }
        // etc
    };
```

So your `dig` variable can't have any exact type.

You should somehow convert every matched type to exactly the same type. The simplest way is to use:

```rust
create_hash(message.as_ref().unwrap(), Groestl256::default())
   .to_slice()
   .to_owned()
```

After that you will have a `Vec<u8>` which you may own and do what you want. But it uses allocation.

Or you can use dynamic dispatching:

```rust
fn create_hash<D: Digest + 'static>(msg: &str, mut hasher: D) -> Box<dyn std::ops::Deref<Target = [u8]>> {
  hasher.update(msg);
  let digest = hasher.finalize();
  Box::new(digest)
}
```

The best, the most complicated and the most Rust-way way is to define some `enum` which will choose it's variant based on given digest.